# delete [] failed, how to find out the reason?

Tags: c++

I have a big mass of code which is running all day.
Once a week, it crashes when trying to release some pointer :

```
delete [] p
```

the back trace (using gdb):

```
0x00007f4f709f2885 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
0x00007f4f709f4065 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
0x00007f4f70a2f7a7 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
0x00007f4f70a350c6 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I want to find out what cause the delete to fail: duplicate delete or something else.
how can I do that?

Comment: the first step would be to actually post code if you want people to be able to help you. if general "how do I debug this kind of problem" advice is what you want, I'd start by logging every time the delete is called, who called it when and why. and start combing through that to find the source of the bug.

Comment: You're going to need to show more code that. You could also give valgrind a try.

Comment: I suggest running your program through valgrind in hopes of finding your bug.

Comment: you had better replay the crash once more in case finding the real reason

Comment: Is it possible that you're `delete`'ing something that was `malloc`'ed instead of `new`'ed?

Comment: @Oren: Being a once-in-a-blue-moon crash, the bug is probably quite far from the delete that crashes. Showing any snippet of code is unlikely to help.

Comment: @MartinshShaiters: GNU stdlibc++'s global `operator new` directly forwards to malloc, so `delete` generally works on `malloc`'d memory just fine. However the `new[]` stores the array element count at the beginning for types with non-trivial destructor and `delete[]` expects to find it there, so if the memory was allocated with `new` and gets deleted by `delete[]`, it will crash except for POD types. Note, that this is the code calling constructors and destructors, which is built-in to the compiler, not part of the library.

Comment: @JanHudec Interesting detail. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that the backtrace contains a call `malloc_printerr`. The function will write the reason to standard error, so remember to have it captured!

Now whether it's mismatched new/delete types, double-delete or invalid pointer altogether, the actual bug happens long before the delete that actually detects it. So gdb is not going to be of much use. You will have to log anything that happens to the relevant pointer and dig up when it went wrong.

- If it is invalid pointer altogether, it would be either uninitialized memory or buffer overrun overwriting it. Review that all objects have correct constructors that zero out any pointer that might be involved. Either problem can also be caught with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), buffer overruns can also be caught with less overhead (but less precision) using [DUMA library](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) or [mudflap](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging) (shipped with gcc).
- If it's double-delete, review that you zero out any involved pointer after deleting it except if in a destructor (and if you are deleting it in destructor, make sure you initialized it in constructor). Add log messages for all operations on the involved pointer and when it crashes, trace back in the log where the pointer appears to have been resurrected. You can also try to do that for invalid pointer.
- If it's mismatched `[]`, make sure you always delete with `[]` when you allocated with `[]` and never otherwise and make sure you are always deleting complete type (C++ accepts deleting incomplete type and it's undefined behaviour).
- Any of the above can also be secondary effect of not properly calling destructors of any object holding the involved pointer. Failing to call destructor might be reason of deleting pointer with incorrect type, deleting pointer to incomplete type or mismatching `[]` on new and delete. In addition to review, add log to any constructors and destructors that might be relevant and check in the log that they are properly matched up.

Don't forget to always log the pointer value so you can actually match the entries. You'll also probably need to write some scripts for analyzing the log (find the entries that are mismatched). And have enough space for it; it's rather easy to generate many **giga**bytes of log this way.

Once you narrow down few operations that are suspect, you might need to write backtrace into the logs. Look at the [backtrace(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace) library function or the [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/).

Answer (score 1):

Write good unit tests, execute them using valgrind and hope you'll catch the bug(s).

Other then that, you can look at your code and search for the bug(s) (for example, ["Good Clues, Easy Bugs" article](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/debugging.html) explains debug techniques).